# ios background tasks - explain sequence of execution?

Tags: ios, background, objective-c-blocks

Could someone explain sequence of execution please in applicationDidEnterBackground?

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {

    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; 
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; 
}];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"\n\nRunning in the background!\n\n");
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; 
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid; 
});
```

My understanding is

1. create identifier for background task and assign block that will be called once time (10 minutes or so) expires
2. dispatch async method, output NSLog. During this time all other methods of the app can be used
3. immediately after NSLog out terminate background task, not waiting for system default expiration

Specifically, after I call NSLog

```
[application endBackgroundTask: background_task]; 
background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

task will be terminated and expirationHandler block will not be called.

I also think my understanding is incorrect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything about your post is basically correct except for one important detail. None of this has anything to do with the `applicationDidEnterBackground` app delegate method.

Any task in your app that might take more than a couple of seconds should be wrapped inside calls to `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and `endBackgroundTask`.

The whole point of wrapping code in these two methods is to notify the OS that you have some processing that needs to keep running even if the app happens to enter the background while it is running. Without these blocks, your app will be killed by the OS after only a few (10?) seconds of trying to run in the background.

Comment: That is interesting! but the dispatch_async has to be within applicationDidEnterBackground, doesn't it? Or any loop will continue to run?

Comment: No, the dispatch_async (and the two begin/endTask methods) can be anywhere in your app and called at any time. The whole idea is you are protecting longer running code just in case the app enters the background. Most of the time the app will execute the code and not go into the background. The only time you would put such code inside  `applicationDidEnterBackground` is when you had some process to run only when the app enters the background. About the only use for this would be for doing some final data persistence in case the app is terminated while in the background.

Comment: One more thing - do I need to call [application endBackgroundTask: background_task] in the expirationHandler?